# Grails is giving resource not found for fullcalendar CSS and JS files

Tags: css, grails, fullcalendar, grails-plugin

I'm trying to use fullcalendar plugin in my grails app and I'm getting a Resource not found for all the fullcalendar css and js files :

```
Error|
Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-1.5.1.0/css/fullcalendar.css
Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-  1.5.1.0/css/fullcalendar.print.css
Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-1.5.1.0/css/fullcalendar.css
Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-  1.5.1.0/css/fullcalendar.print.css
Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-1.5.1.0/js/fullcalendar.min.js
Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-1.5.1.0/css/fullcalendar.css
Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-1.5.1.0/css/fullcalendar.print.css
Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-1.5.1.0/js/fullcalendar.js
```

I'm using

```
compile ":full-calendar:1.5.1.0"
```

in grails 2.3.7

Ideally I guess it should look into the plugins/web-app/css or js folder in grails 2.3.7 where the actual files are present.

I'm including the fullcalendar using

```
<fullcal:resources/>
```

And grails clean did not do any magic this time.

Below is the fullCalendarResources.groovy config file

```
modules = {
    'full-calendar' {
    dependsOn 'jquery'
    dependsOn 'jquery-ui'
    resource url: [ plugin:'full-calendar', dir:'css/fullcalendar', file:'fullcalendar.css' ]
    resource url: [ plugin:'full-calendar', dir:'css/fullcalendar', file:'fullcalendar.print.css' ], attrs: [ media: 'print' ]
    resource url: [ plugin:'full-calendar', dir:'js/fullcalendar',     file:'fullcalendar.js' ], 
        disposition:'head', nominify: true
}
}
```

My basic question is why is it looking in plugin/{plugin-name}/css instead of the web-app folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of permutations, this is what worked for me:

```
 <g:javascript library="full-calendar"/>
 <r:layoutResources/>
```

instead of

```
<fullcal:resources/>
```

in the head

EDIT :

A better way would be to add the fullcalender resources to ApplicationResources.groovy and manually add the js and css to /web-app to and add the application library to your page. As the grails plugin for fullcalender has not been updated.